# Why does the main function in Haskell not have any parameters?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm somewhat new to Haskell. I've worked through one ore two tutorials, but I don't have much experience.

Every function in Haskell is pure, this is, why we can't have any I/O without the IO-monad.
What I don't understand is, why do the program parameters have to be an IO action as well?
The parameters are passed to the program like to a function.
Why can't the parameters be accessed like in a function?

To make things clear, I don't understand, why the main function has to look like this

```
main :: IO()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    print args
```

Instead of this

```
main :: [String] -> IO()
main args = do
    print args
```

I can't see any reason for it, and I haven't found an answer googling around.

Comment: I guess it’s mostly a matter of style, but it could be nice to add as a usability option for familiarity coming from other languages. I also expected this to be allowed when I first learned Haskell, as well as `main :: IO ExitCode`, which is how I learned that `main` is allowed to have type `IO t` for any type `t` (not just `()`), but its result is ignored. A good alternative is something like `main = exitWith =<< mainArgs =<< getArgs` if you want a C-style `mainArgs :: [String] -> IO ExitCode`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a language design choice. Neither approach is strictly better than the other one.

Haskell could have been designed to have a `main` of either kind.

When one does need the program arguments, it would be more convenient to have them passed as function arguments to `main`.

When one does not need the program arguments, having them passed to `main` is slightly cumbersome, since we need to write a longer type, and an additional `_` to discard the `[String]` argument.

Further, `getArgs` lets one access the program arguments anywhere in the program (inside `IO`), while having them passed to `main`, only, can be less convenient since one would then be forced to pass them around in the program, which can be inconvenient.

(Short digression) For what it's worth, I had a similar reaction to yours a long time ago when I discovered that in Java we have `void main()` instead of `int main()` as in C. Then I realized that in most programs I always wrote `return 0;` at the end, so it makes little sense to always require that. In Java that's the implicit default, and when we really need to return something else, we use `System.exit()`. Even if that is the way it's done in a previous language (C, in this case), new languages can choose a new way to make available the same functionality.

Comment: A Java program does not necessarily exit when `main` returns, so it doesn't make sense to tie the process exit code to the main method return value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So there aren't any technical reasons? Are these approaches two approaches exclusive? I could imagine a solution, where you can specify the args parameter, if you want to, but don't have to (sorta like in c++) and still retain the "getArgs" function to use it if deemed necessary.

Comment: @Modi57 You could do that, yes. There are no compelling technical reasons: any alternative could have been implemented. For instance, to implement your `main` variant the compiler could pretend the code reads `main = getArgs >>= yourMain` where `yourMain :: [String] -> IO ()`. It would be trivial to do so for the compiler.

Comment: Another thing to consider: a Haskell program with a plain `main` could in theory run on a device where no `System.Environment` is available (similar to `System.Posix` not being available in some setups).

Comment: In C, the main function need not take parameters. Although it is declared as returning int, it is unique in that it has an implicate `return 0;` at the end

Answer (score 11):

I tend to agree with chi's answer, that there's no clearly compelling reason it has to be done either way, so it really comes down to a somewhat subjective judgement call that was made by a small group of people a long time ago. There's no guarantee that there is going to be any particularly satisfying reason behind it.

Here is some reasoning that comes to my mind (which may or may not have been something the original designers thought of at the time, or even would agree with).

What we're really **love** to be able to do is something like:

```
main :: Integer -> String -> Set Flag -> IO ()
```

(for some hypothetical program that takes as command line arguments an integer, a string, and a set of flags)

Being able to write small command line programs as if they were just a function of their command line arguments would be great! But that would need the operating system (or at least the shell) to understand the types used in a Haskell program and know how to parse them (and what to do if parsing fails, or if there aren't enough arguments, or etc), which isn't going to happen.

Perhaps we could write a wrapper to do that. It could take care of parsing the raw string command line arguments into Haskell types and generating error messages (if needed), and then call `main` for us. But wait, we can do exactly that! We just have to call the wrapper `main` (and rename what we were previously calling `main`)!

The point is this: if you want to think of your program as a simple function of external inputs, that makes a lot of sense, but **`main` is not that function**. `main` works much better as a wrapper that takes care of the ugly details of receiving input over an untyped interface and calling the function that "really is" your program.

Forcing you to include a call to `getArgs` in your set up code makes it more apparent there's more to *handling* command line arguments than just getting access to them, and possibly nudges you to writing some of that extra handling code rather than just writing `main (arg1 : arg2 : _) = do stuffWith arg1 arg2`.

Also, it is **super** trivial to convert the interface we have to the one you want:

```
import System.Environment

main = real_main =<< getArgs

real_main :: [String] -> IO ()
real_main args = print args
```

So you can have it whichever way you prefer!

Comment: Some compelling arguments you make there, I cannot refute ^^. So it seems to be a matter of convenience. I thought it might be nice to have such a commonly used feature directly build in, but I generally understand your reasoning